# GLEW/SFML program not compiling in MinGW - "GLChar" not recognised

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, glew

I am wondering why my code does not compile when I uncomment the line `GLChar* test = "Test";`

Here is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// SFML
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

const int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;
//GLChar* test = "Test";

int main() {
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT),
              "OpenGL",
              sf::Style::Default,
              sf::ContextSettings(24, 0, 0, 3, 1));


    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            } else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized) {
                glViewport(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
            }
        }

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        // clear the buffers
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is very confusing to me that it does not seem to work when I uncomment `GLChar* test = "Test"`, given that `glClearColor` and `glClear` work fine otherwise. It does not matter whether it is within main() or declared globally, the error is the same.

The error is:

```
E:\Downloads\SFML-Game\src\main.cpp:11:1: error: 'GLChar' does not name a type
GLChar* test = "Test";
```

My libraries are linked properly, I believe - here is my relevant CMakeLists.txt area:

```
target_link_libraries(game
libglew32.a
libopengl32.a
libsfml-main-d.a
libsfml-graphics-d.a
libsfml-audio-d.a
libsfml-system-d.a
libsfml-window-d.a
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watch the case: the correct type spelling is `GLchar`, not `GLChar`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This seems silly now. I am yet to setup autocomplete in my environment which would have saved me here. I've had so many linker errors lately I didn't think it would be anything else!